# Measuring power consumption / current of an Arduino using a multitester

Tags: arduino

What is the correct way to measure the power consumption and / or current draw of an Arduino using a multitester?

Comment: Multitester? Do you mean multimeter, or do you have a different piece of equipment?

Comment: Yes, multitester, somekind like this: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Compact-Digital-Multitester-With-Diode/dp/B000L0RINQ , I think it is same tools, just different name, cmiiw.

Comment: I measured power consumption of ATMega328P at different voltages and frequencies and made this chart https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v2LGArlAkp5wiknlZEDknqD65P9FCHSeSo-Op2iwd0I/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

Comment: If you could find DC power source you can see the current. Like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=381Rg5YDmRM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Select the milliamp range on the meter
- Connect the red lead to the meter's milliamp socket
- disconnect the power supply from the board
- connect the ground of the supply connector to the ground of the board connector
- Connect the red probe of the meter to the positive connector on the supply
- Connect the black probe of the meter to the positive connector on the board.
- observe the meter reading
- multiply milliamps/1000 by voltage to get power in watts

  - voltage measured with second meter
  - rated voltage of supply
  - voltage measured earlier or later